# Regular launch of http requests in celery task

Tags: python, python-requests, celery, celerybeat

I'm using requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) 's session in celery tasks.

I have two endpoints that I need to periodically fetch.

```
import requests
from celery import shared_task

yahoo = requests.Session()



@shared_task
def fetch_yahoo():
    url = 'http://some_yahoo_url'
    download = yahoo.get(url)

    do_something_with(download)
```

Problem is that, task stops running after some time. 
(do_something_with is not called)

Is there something wrong with my usage with requests.Session?

Comment: solved ?  I also need fix this issue

Comment: sorry did not find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need celery beat 
https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/celery.beat.html
It allow launch periodical celery tasks. Add in `celeryconfih.py`

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

class CeleryConfig:
    beat_schedule = {
        'my-regular-task': {
            'task': '<path to task call>',
            'schedule': timedelta(minutes=5),
            'args': (),
            'options': {
                'expires': 60,
            },
        },
       'my-cron-task': {
            'task': '<path to task call>',
           'schedule': crontab(hour=4, minute=11),
           'args': (),
           'options': {
               'expires': 60,
           },
       }, 
   }
```

And then launch with `-B` flag

```
celery -A  app.celery -B ...
```

Comment: OP in the question is using `celery` already and this answer recommends using one of celery's functionality so I don't see it as a problem, @geisterfurz007

Comment: Looks like I missed cleaning up old comments :) Thanks @EshaanBansal! My comment was made before an edit turning a link to a code block. Removed it (and will remove this in a bit as well).